# Wordpress installed on a Sub-directory

Tags: wp-config

I've already read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) and followed the steps, however I can't get it work yet.

- My Wordpress URL: `http://mydomain.com/web` (this is where it's installed)
- My Site URL: `http://mydomain.com`

I've copied `index.php` and `.htaccess` to /public_html which is the root directory.

/.index.php

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'web/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

/web/index.php

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'wp-blog-header.php' );
```

/.htaccess (the same as /web/.htaccess)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I can still access to my admin page on `http://mydomain.com/web/wp-admin`, but Wordpress content media isn't recognized yet because I once changed "wp-content" folder name to "media" (using iThemes Security plugin) and this to `wp-config.php`

/web/wp-config.php

```
<?php
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://mydomain.com/web/media' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/web/media' );
```

So, media (plugins, themes, language) isn't recognized.

I've tried with `http://mydomain.com/wp-admin` and it doesn't redirects me to `http://mydomain.com/web/wp-admin` either.

Answer (score 1):

Looks link you're missing the forward slash / which is probably causing it to not locate the right files

/.index.php

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/web/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

/web/index.php

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

/.htaccess (the same as /web/.htaccess)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

/web/wp-config.php (delete what you have and replace with this right above the thats all part )

```
define('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'media');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME );
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME );
```

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Comment: The last part I just like to use but you don't have to

Comment: You were right about the slash! however, media isn't recognized :/